# Regex stop on certain character

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
@(.*)\((.*)\)
```

And I'm trying to get two matches from this string

```
@YouTube('dqrtLyzNnn8') @Vimeo('124719070')
```

I need it to stop after the closing `)`, so I get two matches instead of one.

[**See example on Regexr**](http://www.regexr.com/3arf4)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/787480 .

Comment: Thanks for that. I changed the question a little now. I want it to stop at the ending parenthesis istead of a HTML tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) (`?`):

```
@(.*?)\((.*?)\)
```

[DEMO](http://regexr.com/3arf7)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a negated character class:

```
@([^()]+)\(([^()]+)\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is trying to eat as much characters as possible.
Look at the next regex:

```
echo "@YouTube('dqrtLyzNnn8') @Vimeo('124719070')" | 
   sed 's/@[a-zA-Z]*(\([^)]*\)[^@]*@[a-zA-Z]*(\([^)]*\).*/\1 \2/'
```

I do not know the exact requirements, you might me easier of starting with another command:

```
echo "@YouTube('dqrtLyzNnn8') @Vimeo('124719070')"  | cut -d\' -f2,4
```